# Weighted 2D kernel density heatmap in R

Tags: r, heat-map, kernel-density, weighted

I have visual observations from repeat transect surveys (individual sighting locations based on bearing and distance to transect) that I use to create 2D kernel density heatmaps. Currently I do so with `ggplot()` and `stat_density2d()` in R. `stat_density2d()` uses `MASS::kde2d()` under the hood. However, I have unequal effort across different sections of my transect and want to weight my kernel density estimates by this differing effort. `kde2d()` does not offer weighing. The usual approach I found would include replicating respective rows to standardize effort, but wouldn't that result in incorrect count estimates? It also requires integer 'weighs' as opposed to proportions.

Are there alternative approaches/packages that allow weighing of 2D kernel density estimates? I know I could calculate them outside of the `ggplot()` call and then feed the results directly into `geom_contour()` instead of calculating it inside `stat_density2d()`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=easting, y=northing)) +
stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(level)), geom = "polygon", contour=T, contour_var='count') +
  geom_path(data=transect_cords, aes(x=x, y=y), color='white')
```

[image: Kernel density map]

Comment: Can you make a sample data set? I'm not sure how your "unequal effort" is defined.

Comment: I'll try. Unequal sample effort as in: each section (leg) has a number and across 5 surveys, legs 1-4 and 10 were completed five times, legs 5 and 6 were completed three times, leg 7 was only completed twice, and legs 8-9 were completed four times. Something like this.

Comment: And your data are something like position on transect (x,y), bearing and distance to sighting (say, (b, d), from which with (x,y) you get location of sighting), and transect leg id (which you sort of get from (x,y)) or maybe explicitly if you have the leg with each sighting?

Comment: Correct. I have position on transect which I use to calculate position of the animal, date, time, and leg ID for each sighting

Comment: Have you looked at alternative kernel smoothing codes like in the `ks` package, such as its `kde` function which has a `w` argument for weights? Also there are some specialised transect sampling functions discussed in the Environmetrics Task View: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Environmetrics.html